# C# Best Way to Save Text Files into Objects

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a group of delimited text files I need to read, create a class and objects, and store members inside.  I am a beginner that's just looking to be pointed in the right direction. Any help would be appreciated greatly. Thank you very much.

I made a class with objects with:

```
public string left;
public string right;
```

and my form code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
    of.ShowDialog();
    textBox1.Text = of.FileName;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text);
    textBox2.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    // sr.Close();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] split1 = textBox2.Text.Split(';');
    foreach (string segment in split1)
    {
        //split sub-segment
        string[] split2 = segment.Split(':');
        //check if it's valid
        if (split2.Count().Equals(2))
        {
            id textfile = new id();
            textfile.left += // ????
            id textfile1 = new id();
            textfile.right += // ????
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you are asking.

Comment: sorry c#. forgot to add that

Comment: Are you sure you want to use delimited text, and not a far more robust solution such as JSON or XML?

Comment: I just need to read in a text file and instead of displaying it I need to store it into a string list

Comment: mason I am open to suggestions, still pretty new to this and thats how i learned.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, it's much preferable to use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) or [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml) to save data to text files rather than delimited text or custom formats. That's because good JSON and XML support is available in my languages and it's easy to work with.

```
public class MyCustomClass //this class will hold your data
{
    public string Left {get; set;}
    public string Right {get;set;}
}

MyCustomClass mcc=new MyCustomClass(); //create an instance of your class
mcc.Left="yes"; //set some properties
mcc.Right="nope";
string json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mcc); //convert to JSON string
File.WriteAllText("mcc.txt",json); //save to file

//later on, when you want to read it back from the file
string json=File.ReadAllText("mcc.text"); //read from file into a string
MyCustomClass mcc=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomClass>(json); //convert the string back to an instance of MyCustomClass
```

Above, we use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) which is a library available for the .NET Framework ([available on NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)). We use it to convert our object to a string (serialize) and then later on to convert it back to an object (deserialize). Note that in order to use the JsonConvert class, you'll need the Json.NET references and to add a using statement at the top of your class `using Newtonsoft.Json;`.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). When you have a known structure (like your class with `string left` and `string right`), you want to write that structure out to a text file. Then later, you want to read that information back in and automatically populate the class with each of the values.

As mason pointed out, JSON is fairly easy to setup. You create the class structure that you want, and tell JSON to save that out to a specified file (via `SerializeObject`).

Since .NET allows for [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29), JSON is able to turn the text file back into the contents of a `class` without you having to manually 'myClass.left = [some_value_from_json]'.

Personally, I'd go with JSON or XML, since naming your blocks of data means it is both more readable, and that your parser is able to handle someone rearranging the data (it doesn't matter if the file defines `left` before it defines `right`). If you rearranged a .CSV file, then you get data corruption.

Answer (score 1):

Reading delimited files is common and there are many approaches to the subject. Personally I use a [streamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader) to read in the file and split it on the delimiter:

```
 Foo foo = new Foo(); // custom class
 string file = "export.CSV";
 if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
 {             
      // Do work
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
      {
          while (!reader.EndOfStream)
          {
              // split on the delimeter
              var readLine = reader.ReadLine();
              if (readLine == null) continue;
              var lines = readLine.Split(new[] { ',' });

              foreach (string s in lines)
              {
                  // do something with the data from the line

              }  
              // alternatively, you could specify your objects if your files
              // layout never changes. Just be careful to catch the exceptions! 
              foo.bar = lines[0];
              foo.baz = lines[1];

          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: What happens if there's an internal comma?

Comment: The only thing I miss with this is storing the value of each split, thats what im hung up on.  I dont want to display it just store the objects as a list

Comment: @mason csv files have many approaches and pitfalls (embedded commas are one of them), and there are many better libraries than my quick code here. Personally for delimited files I like tabs, rare to find embedded `\t` :-)

Comment: My point is that there's a ton of pitfalls associated with delimited files, and that it's much more robust (and simpler!) to implement saving data as JSON, XML, or some other well supported format.

Comment: @mason - I support legacy systems that cannot consume JSON and XML support is available partially. There is not a business case for JSON/XML everywhere and delimited files will likely be around for a long time. I understand your point, but the OP asked about delimited files.

Comment: I am the downvoter, I do not like recommending bad solutions. You're right, delimited files will be around for a long time. But that's not a valid excuse to continue using a bad format in my opinion. The OP asked about delimited files, probably because he/she did not know what other options were out there, and explicitly stated they were open to other ideas. In addition, rolling your own CSV writer is a notoriously bad idea. Using existing libraries would be better.

Comment: @mason - What you consider a bad solution many industries consider the *only* solution.

Comment: @RobertH will this work if i integrate the open file part from my code above?

Comment: @user3617347 No reason why it wouldn't - give it a shot and see what you end up with